# How do I get plain text from an API?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm sorry just asking like this, but I'm new to JSON and API-related Stuff.

```
@bot.command()
async def insult(ctx):
  resp = requests.get("https://insult.mattbas.org/api/insult")
  if 300 > resp.status_code >= 200:
      content = resp.json()  #We have a dict now.
  else:
      content = f"Recieved a bad status code of {resp.status_code}."
  await ctx.send(content)
```

The API displays plain text and I can't figure out how to get it.
I can however get other API results which do not have plain text.

Please help.

Comment: `resp.body` or `resp.content`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call resp.content or resp.text instead of json().

```
@bot.command()
async def insult(ctx):
  resp = requests.get("https://insult.mattbas.org/api/insult")
  if 300 > resp.status_code >= 200:
      content = resp.content  #We have a dict now.
  else:
      content = f"Recieved a bad status code of {resp.status_code}."
  await ctx.send(content)
```

Comment: Ah thanks but resp.content brings stuff like:
`b'insult\n'`
so i used resp.text